# Always pass a column via a MySQL function to encrypt and decrypt

Tags: mysql

I would like to encrypt and decrypt my data in database itself. Only thing I will pass secret key and iv from laravel application through MySQL view or temporary table for security purpose.

All need is
Can we pass a column via MySQL function whenever it accessed in insert or select or select where conditions?

So that we could encrypt it while insert. Decrypt it while select.

Which means, decrypt or encrypt functions should not be used in direct queries. MySQL should manipulate then during select or insert.

Is there anyway we can achieve this?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use TDE https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217993/how-can-i-enable-transparent-data-encryption-tde-on-mysql-5-6